# Obtaining Target-Specific Variables in included Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have two targets in my project, let's call them client.c and server.c.

If I'm building for client, I'd like to set a variable, APPS, to be:

*APPS += client_app*

If I'm building for server, I'd like set this variable to be:

*APPS += server_app*

This **APPS** variable is used in an included Makefile (*Makefile.include*), which checks to see if APPS is defined, and then parses it if it's set.

```
ifdef APPS
  blah blah blah
endif
```

I am currently trying to do this like so...

```
all: client server
client: APPS += client_app
client: client.$(TARGET)
  @echo $(APPS)
server: APPS += server_app
server: server.$(TARGET)
  @echo $(APPS)
include ../Makefile.include
```

... This builds the targets and echos out APPS when building either the client or server. However Makefile.include never sees APPS as being set.I'm assuming this is a quirk of having a Target Specific Variable.

How would I go about ensuring that my included Makefile can also see this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.  Target-specific variables are *only* set in the context of [the recipe for the target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).  So, they have no value when the included makefile is parsed; that's not in the context of any particular rule.

Without knowing what the *blah blah blah* actually does in your makefile it's difficult to suggest alternatives.  However, assuming you can't simplify this and it must be a set of make directives inside an `ifdef`, then you can use recursive `make` to do this:

```
all: client server

client: APPS += client_app
server: APPS += server_app

client server:
        $(MAKE) APPS=$(APPS) $@.$(TARGET)

include ../Makefile.include
```

Comment: At first I though the second pass has something to do with it. You really know your makefiles. +1  I find it easiest to simply use MAKECMDGOALS.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try!

Comment: Apologies it took me so long to get around to trying this out. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of the additional makefile is not the issue here. The variable would not be seen regardless.

The ifdef will not see the definition of the variable APPS  because it is only visible to the specific target it was defined with.

Instead remove the assignments to APPS altogether and use the special variable MAKECMDGOALS, which holds the list of goals specified in the command line:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),client)

$(info client)  #do client stuff here

else ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),server)

$(info server)  #and server stuff here

else

$(error Invalid targets)

endif
```